# Drop Down List Event failed to execute

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu, selectedindexchanged

In my drop-down list, the SelectedIndexChanged event is not firing. I set AutoPostBack="True" but it's still not firing. Setting EnableViewState to True or False makes no difference either.

Here's my code:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlSheerName" runat="server" Width="250" AutoPostBack="True"
 OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlSheerName_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:DropDownList>

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    loggedInUserId = Convert.ToString(Session["LoggedInUserId"]);
    if (loggedInUserId == "")
    {
        Response.Redirect("Login.aspx");
    }
    if (Page.IsPostBack == false)
    {
        BindCompanyDropDown();

    }
}

protected void ddlSheerName_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Bindcolumnname();
}

public void BindCompanyDropDown()
{
    try
    {
        objData = new DBFile();
        DataSet dsCompanies = objData.GetCompaniesList(loggedInUserId);
        if (dsCompanies != null)
        {
            if (dsCompanies.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                ddlselectcompany.DataSource = dsCompanies;
                ddlselectcompany.DataTextField = "CompanyName";
                ddlselectcompany.DataValueField = "CompanyID";
                ddlselectcompany.DataBind();
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        lblMsg.Text = ex.Message;
    }
}
```

Comment: make sure that javascript is enabled on your browser. See also browser console if there is any javascript errors.

Comment: Hi stefanE.... i'm not using JavaScript.I saw Browser Console is Also but still that is not firing...

Comment: @R1 you might not be aware of this but autopostback uses javascript in the background hence it is important its enabled on the broswer

Comment: Ya i'm checked Javascript is enabled...

Comment: ok I just tested your code and it seems to work fine when you change the dropdown value the selectedIndexChanged event fires successfully. I will be more then happy to post my test code on here for you to see but it dosent look much different to yours.

Comment: try it on another browser. It is highly possible that it is related to browser.

Comment: K Bobby... send that test code to me...Thanks yr....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Viewstate must be enabled for this particular code to work and Javascript must be enabled for AutoPostBack to function.

Answer (score 1):

The dropdown itself doesn't cause the event to fire.

You must actually change the selected item for the event to fire.

Answer (score 0):

Is your event registred in the designer?
Select the dropdown and check the events assigned to it.

Comment: **Please _don’t_ use signatures or taglines in your posts**. Read the [FAQ entry](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures) for more info. Thanks!